# RFC6960 requested ocsp service definition

Tags: ocsp, asn1, rfc

In RFC6960 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960) is written the request data contains the requested service and the OCSP responder checks, if the requested service is provided.

But when I had a look on OCSP's ASN.1 specification (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960#page-31) I couldn't find the definition of the requested service anywhere in the request's specification. Is the service (lookup the certificate's state) defined implicitly?